# Database Publishing Using Web Deploy

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

I've had success in using Web Deploy to publish my web page, however the database (schema and data) are not being published at all.

- .NET 4.5
- MVC 5
- EF Code First 6
- Visual Studio 2013 for Web

[image]

I get no errors, the remote database connection is fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: What errors you are getting when you tried to browse to the website?

Comment: Hi Rosdi, it's not so much about browsing the website, it's the fact that when I look at the database, there aren't any tables.

Comment: The tables will be created when you first browse the website.

Comment: They do not get created I'm afraid.

Comment: Which back to my first question, what errors you are getting when you browse the website?

Comment: Ah! Sorry I was interpreting your question incorrect, there is no actual error whilst browing, however when I try and create an account (database interaction) I get: `[SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot find the object &quot;dbo.Listings&quot; because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.]`
Naturally, the `Listings` table does not yet exist.

Comment: Try adding `[Authorize]` attribute on your `Controller` or `Action`. You will be asked to login but see if the tables are created.

Comment: I'm unclear about what you mean, which `Controller` are you referring to?

Comment: Can you check if you have permission to create new tables for your connection string?

Comment: Hi Parth, I certainly do, I can manually go into SSMS and create a table no problems.

Answer (score 1):

In iis right-click the site that you are configuring, point to Deploy, and then click Configure Web Deploy Publishing in "Enter SQL SERVER connection String enter your database connection string
[image]

Comment: I'm deploying through Visual Studio.

Comment: @user1470994 Before publish from visual studio in IIS server config SQL server connection string same as that picture

Comment: Thanks, however, that still did not work and is what I already have in my original question. I solved my problem by pointing the 'defaultconnection' to my remote server in my Web.Config file.